# Triple DES Decrypting: ECB mode cannot use IV

Tags: java, encryption

I have Java code sitting on a server for decrypting data that I am trying to run locally for some testing. The code runs fine on the server but throws an error in my local build.

> ECB mode cannot use IV

```
    public static String triple_des_decrypt(String key, String data)
    {
        try
        {
            //needs to have an even number of digits
            if (key.length() % 2 == 1)
            {
                key = "0" + key;
            }
            byte[] desKey = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());

            // pad out key for cipher routine
            int deskeyLength = desKey.length;
            byte[] desKey24 = new byte[24];

            int copySize = 16;
            if (copySize > deskeyLength)
            {
                copySize = deskeyLength;
            }
            System.arraycopy(desKey, 0, desKey24, 0, copySize);

            copySize = 8;
            if (copySize > deskeyLength)
            {
                copySize = deskeyLength;
            }
            System.arraycopy(desKey, 0, desKey24, 16, 8);

            DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(desKey24);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
            String algo = "DESede";


            SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algo).generateSecret(keySpec); 
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv); //Error thrown here
            byte[] byteData = Hex.decodeHex(data.toCharArray());
            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(byteData);

            char tempString[] = Hex.encodeHex(decryptedData);
            String decryptedString = new String(tempString).toUpperCase();
            return decryptedString;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I'm not familiar with encryption and I'm at a loss as to why this error is thrown.

**Edit** Removing the IV parameter from `cipher.init` fixes the issue, but I'm still curious as to why no error is thrown in a different environment.

Comment: *...I'm still curious as to why no error is thrown in a different environment.*.  Why don't provide a little information about how these environments differ.

Comment: Have you solved?

Answer (score 2):

ECB doesn't perform chaining between blocks so there is no way to use initialization vector ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB))). Therefore, you get the error message that ECB mode cannot use IV